# When I download eclipse what version of JDK and JRE is being used and how can I change it?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, ide, java-7

I have downloaded the new eclipse 2022-06 and I wanted to know that what version of Java does it run on. What is the JDK and JRE and how can I create a project to run on Java 7 with a compatible JRE? Where do I select those settings or what do I additionally need to download?

Comment: If you want to use a different Java JRE/JDK than the embedded one used to run Eclipse with, you have to configure it (in your case a Java 7 JDK; a JDK is needed to see the sources of the system library) in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: To answer your question, how to configure the JDKs in Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Here you can add as many as you want.

Comment: Usually, the JRE to run Eclipse with is embedded into the installation. No need to have a JRE installed for that.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose will this change for every project I create after I change it?

Comment: In these preferences you simply add all JDKs that you need for your projects. E.g. I have JDK8, JDK11, and JDK17 in there. You can select which one to use for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official documentation: [Eclipse/Installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM)
You will find for each version of Eclipse the required JRE/JDK to run it.

Instead, if you are looking for how to run a project with a different JRE/JDK, you can take a look at this guide: [How to Change Java Version in an Eclipse Project](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version)

Comment: That's the Java to run Eclipse with, but the question was about _"a project to run on Java 7"_. So independent of the Java with which Eclipse is run, a Java 7 JDK has to be configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.